# Disallowing keystrokes in the textarea with jQuery

Tags: jquery, textarea

In the Twitter signup process, they do not allow you to input any character other than alphanumeric keywords

What would be a good way, efficient way of doing so? The plugins available seems to be a little too slow for my liking, so i was wondering if anyone had more efficient way of doing so

Comment: Be aware you probably want to filter pasting from the clipboard too, and re-validate the string on the server.

Comment: right on, thanks 4 e reminder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen for `keydown`/`keypress`, check the character code, and if it's not something you want `preventDefault()` or `return false`

### Implementation

Here's an example with jQuery. This creates a list of 'valid' keycodes, initially populated with formatters (Escape, Backspace etc) and then populates the array with other valid keys.

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    var a=[8,9,13,16,17,18,20,27,35,36,37,38,39,40,45,46,91,92];
    var k = e.which;

    for (i = 48; i < 58; i++) // 0-9 on top of keyboard
        a.push(i);
    for (i = 65; i < 91; i++) // a-z
        a.push(i);
    for (i = 96; i < 106; i++) // 0-9 on numpad
        a.push(i);

    if (!(a.indexOf(k)>=0)) // prevents disabled keys
        e.preventDefault();
});​
```

You can also use this array to check validity of the username before submitting, by iterating through each character in the string and making sure it's one of these.

### Try it out here

http://jsfiddle.net/vRJ2v/

Answer (score 2):

I use this plugin:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-keyfilter/

I haven't had any issues with delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an event handler for the `keydown` event which stops the propagation of the event if the text does not match a regular expression for example.